# Updating old entries on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have some JSON entries in MongoDB but I plan to add new attributes into all my entries, like how you would create a new column and appoint a default value in RDBMS.

Is there any way to do it with MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that every new document needs to be guaranteed to have the new fields, I'm afraid that it's not possible in MongoDB itself, because it is schemaless. I am however not familiar with mongoose, and there can be a solution using it.

If, like your title suggests, you just want to add the new fields to all existing documents you can do it with an update with empty filter like this:

```
db.collection.updateMany({}, {"newfield1":"val1","newfield2":"val2"})
```

Comment: MongoDB 3.2 introduced document validation (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document-validation/), which can be configured to require certain fields to be present